# Layout of doubled SW pin on buck converter IC

Tags: pcb, dc-dc-converter, buck, layout, pinout

I'm working on a PCB for the [MP2617](http://www.monolithicpower.com/DesktopModules/DocumentManage/API/Document/getDocument?id=1114). That IC integrates a buck converter and has two physical SW pins sandwiching the VIN pin, as shown in my tentative layout below. No other pins on the IC are doubled. So I'm wondering if the doubled SW pin is to increase the current capacity or just to provide more layout options. I should note that the device will be operating at the top end of its input voltage and step-down ratio capability (14 V to 3.6 V), and 2/3 of its output current rating of 3 A. The estimated inductor peak current is 2.5 A

- can I safely leave one of them unconnected?
- should I connect them together by a 10 mil trace inside the IC footprint (replacing the existing ground trace), even though it will come very close to the small signal pins on the right hand side, and the 10 mil trace will have little current capacity?
- should I connect them together by a trace and two vias on the left of the IC, at the cost of reducing the width of the PGND and VIN traces?

The datasheet is mute on that matter.

[image: PCB]

Comment: I would guess it is one to have it nearer to power ground for actual switching, and the other  have nearer to the bootstrap for the bootstrap cap. Btw. are you sure it is a good idea to connect power ground and analogue ground at that place?

Comment: @PlasmaHH I'm quite sure there are better places to connect them

Comment: As for the ground, I am sure of nothing, as this is my first PCB ;-) But I have seen such a layout with AGND connected to PGND under the IC in [AN136](http://cds.linear.com/docs/en/application-note/an136f.pdf), albeit with a larger package that has a thermal pad. What would be the issue with the current ground connection? The AGND occupies the top right quadrant, not mixing with PGND and connects to PGND only under the IC.

Comment: @Damien But your AGND doesn't connect to anything else. Connecting grounds together is best done in a star-configuration, but this looks like analogue components reach the AGND through your PGND domain. That could give annoying oscillations or reduced performance, because switching noise gets "injected" from PGND into your Analogue reference ground in the chip. May not happen, but 2A switching currents... it definitely could.

Comment: AGND leaves the IC footprint through the pin at the top and forms a large pour over the whole top right quadrant of the board, where the small signal circuits are. I should have included that in the screencap.

Comment: But for sure I could make it leave the chip on the right hand side. Minor reshuffling needed, but nothing major.

Comment: @Damien A bit more of a perspective would have helped, no doubt, but no matter. The point is, your high currents come out of the PGND pins and as I see it, it looks like the small-signal return passes those pins before it reaches a hard/safe ground, which is less than desirable.

Answer (score 1):

you say no other pins are doubled, but I see the PGND under two pins as well, possibly even four.

This is a synchronous buck chip with internal switch, it's very possible the low-impedance path is (, as Plasma says in the comments,) between the three pins closely put together:
 VIN, SW and PGND;
where the top SW is more of a looped-around after thought. The power path should definitely include the other pin with least amount of impedance possible (few vias in series or many in parallel and thickest trace as you can get).

It is possible the SW pins are in direct parallel on the chip and they both jump over the bulk VIN with wire bonds of the same or similar description, but in matters of chip design it seems less likely. If they both offer a same or similar path, the only thing I can think of would be one pad being closer to the high-side switch and the other closer to the low-side switch, which would then again mean both need to be connected as low-impedance as you can.

Comment: There is only one PGND, the other pins connected to it are configuration pins that can be driven high or low to set the circuit behaviour. I see what you mean about the top SW pin being an afterthought. Wouldn't they mention it in the datasheet if it had no current capability?

Comment: If I want to connect the inductor to both pins or to the lower pin, then either (a) the path from VIN to CIN has to go through vias or (b) the path from SW to the inductor has to go through vias or (c) the return from CIN to PGDN has to go through a via. None of these seem good.

Comment: @Damien Fair enough. It is not impossible that they equipped the other SW pin with the capability to be used as a main connection, but with power electronics one should always assume that 2 pins in a power path both need to be connected for carrying the load, unless specifically told otherwise in the datasheet.

Comment: Ah, I see another option (d) the second SW trace goes under CIN, between its pads, and joins the inductor without vias.

Comment: @Damien if you can, I think your D is the best, moving the "signal" GND connections away from under the chip, leaving room for a SW trace. Power carrying traces >> signal traces. I have no time to fully scour the PDF, so I cannot make promises about best practise, but if you're sure it tells you nothing, and you are stuck to 2-sided (which you probably are for a first design, no shame in that..) I would give preference to D.

Comment: And the proximity to the signal pins (the whole top and right hand side pins of the IC) won't be an issue? I actually meant routing it under CIN which is the large capacitor on the lower left, but what you suggest is also possible.

Comment: @Damien if you can route it along under the CIN in the shortest possible way, that would probably be better. Capacitive coupling is less likely with the signal pins, but it can add to other problems to tip the scales, for sure. If you can get the length difference between both SW tracks small, that's preferable, but not by making one excessively long (and possibly thin).

Comment: @ Asmyldof I'll try that, thanks. The route under CIN would be 7 mm long, ie 4 mm longer than the other. Yet another option I can see: (e) modify the pads to shave 0.51 mm off the right end of the VIN pin (max VIN current is 500 mA) and make a direct connection (covered in resist) between the two switches that doesn't get close to the other pins.

Comment: @Damien go with under the cap then. Add to that the ponderings of AGND and you should have something that does something, which is more than can be said of my first ever try ;-). But we're allowed to forget about 20+ years ago, I'd think.

Comment: Here are the two possible routes shown at once then: [here](http://i.imgur.com/7i4GTCW.png). I sure hope so! But if not I'll try again ;-) It has been fun learning all that.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/26347/discussion-between-asmyldof-and-damien).

Answer (score 1):

This is a fairly high frequency (up to 1.6MHz) switcher- you may wish to follow the manufacturer's [evaluation board](http://www.monolithicpower.com/DesktopModules/DocumentManage/API/Document/GetDocument?id=1115) layout on this particular matter. As you can see, the pins are both connected together on a 2-layer layout.

[image]

Comment: I didn't know about that demo board — thanks, that will be a great help.